# Prove that: $n$ has a prime divisor which is not smaller than $11$.

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

Let integer $n>10$ such that $n=\overline{a_{m}a_{m-1}a_{m-2}...a_{0}}$ where: $a_i \in {(1;3;7;9)}$, $i=\overline{0,m}$
Prove that: $n$ has a prime divisor which is not smaller than $11$.

Here or what I tried:

Notice that: $n$ is odd

Now $n$ can be written as:

$$n=(10^{a_1}+10^{a_2}+...10^{a_n}).1+(10^{b_1}+10^{b_2}+...10^{b_n}).3+(10^{c_1}+10^{c_2}+...10^{c_n}).7+(10^{d_1}+10^{d_2}+...10^{d_n}).9$$

Have: $$10 \equiv -1 mod 11$$

But frome there, I can't make anything more. Can anyone continue with this please, my teacher said that I should use number system like decimal system!

Comment: Well, the only counterexamples would be of the form $3^a7^b$ so you just need to prove that no such expression (other than the obvious small ones) can be written using only those four digits.  That said, it's not clear (to me) how to show that.

Comment: Casual inspection appears to suggest that the penultimate (meaning, in this case, the tens place) digit of such a number is always even.  If true, that might not be difficult to show (just need to work $\pmod {100}$).

Comment: I don't understand much:( The $n$ are written by these numbers $1,3,7,9$ example: $133997,97133$

Comment: Well, I gave you an *extremely* strong hint.  I suggest following it.

Comment: Is it said $n$ can be written as $3^a7^b$?

Comment: If it has no prime factor $≥11$ then it can be (it's clearly odd and prime to $5$)

Comment: @lulu in fact working mod $20$ works

Comment: the idea is that to prove everything of that form has a prime factor other than 3 or 7, you prove the contrapositive: nothing with only prime factors 3 and 7 can be of that form. And you have been given a hint as to why they can't be of that form.

Comment: Luc, the last digit is not 5 or even, so it’s not divisible by 2 or 5, so the only possible prime factors less than 11 are 3 and 7. Show that the second lowest digit of 3^n 7^m is even, by calculating all thr powers modulo 20.

Comment: Thank a lots! @gnasher729

Comment: @gnasher729, can you help me more please? When I use modulo 20, it still complicated :((

Comment: Powers of 3: 1, 3, 9, 27->7, 21->1 and repeat. Times 7: 7, 21->1, 63->3, 49->9. Nothing new, so higher powers of 7 make no difference.